# SignalP Error message: Can't locate FASTA.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I installed SignalP 4.0 on a mac. I changed the path of the file folder directory and the output directory as described.

Then, when I try the test script by typing:

```
   ./signalp -t euk -f summary test/euk10.fsa > euk10.fsa.summary_out
```

Error message:

```
    Can't locate FASTA.pm in @INC (you may need to install the FASTA module)(@INC contains: ....) at ./signalp line 80.
```

in the file signalp line 80 is:

```
 use FASTA;
```

I installed BioPerl which contains a module Bio::BD::Fasta, which I guess is what I need.

However, it still output the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the 'P'. Try: `$ENV{SIGNALP} = '/path/to/signalp/directory';`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see this in the installation instructions anywhere, but if you edit the `signalp` executable in that package, you'll see some settings that need to be customized.  On line 14, you need to edit the default path to point to your signalp directory location by editing the line

`$ENV{SIGNAL} = '/path/to/signalp/directory';`

That will allow the program to find the `FASTA.pm` module located in the `lib` directory of that package.  It doesn't look like there's any need to install any other packages for this.